# databricks python dbutils can't move file from one directory to another

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a file that I can see in my current working directory:

```
%sh
pwd
ls
```

The output of above is:

```
/databricks/driver
conf
sample.csv
logs
```

I want to move the `sample.csv` file from here to `Workspace/Shared` directory for which I am using `dbutils.fs.mv`:

```
dbutils.fs.mv("dbfs:/databricks/driver/sample.csv","dbfs:/Workspace/Shared/")
```

but this gives error as `java.is.FileNotFoundException:dbfs:/databricks/driver/sample.csv`

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

when you're executing command on via `%sh`, it's executed on the driver node, so file is local to it.  But you're trying to copy file as it's on the DBFS already, and then it isn't found.  You need to change scheme from `dbfs` to `file` to point to the file on the driver node, like this:

```py
dbutils.fs.mv("file:///databricks/driver/sample.csv","dbfs:/Workspace/Shared/")
```

Comment: So if I want to copy the file to my workspace directory in databricks (the workspace tab in databricks UI), should I use `file` or `dbfs`. I tried both and it executes without error but I don't see the file in my workspace directory via UI

Comment: To make visible in UI you need to use dbfs. But you original file should be specified via file://